# Merging several jQuery selections into one to then traverse with .each

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to add a click event to most of the links on a page. The problem is that I need to do it by selecting the container of the link rather than simply `$('a')`, because I need to use the container's class as one or the arguments in the click handler call.

I'd like to just have one large collection that I can iterate through with .each and bind the handler. There are going to be a couple dozen different containers, at least, so is there a way to do this without a very long string of `$(class1).add(class2).add(class3)`, etc ?

The page has a number of blocks on it, and sections. When a link is clicked within whatever the user has defined as a logical block/section, a code needs to be passed. In one case, the code may be a container containing a linked list of tags, so all tags would have a [great[grand]]parent and the same code. The reason the container is what has to carry the code instead of the link is that it's a dynamic site, and the contents of that block/region can be changed by the editor at any time, so it's the Location of that block on the screen that determines the code, and not what is in it. So when the page loads, the containers (sections/blocks) are known, and what their code should be. They are unaware of their contents (as am I), and the links are unaware of their container.

[My apologies to whoever added the comment that I accidentally deleted when I tried to delete my reply]

```
<div class="code1">
  <div>
    <h2>title</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
       <li><a>link1</a></li>
       <li><a>link2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="code2">
  <div>
    <img>
    <p></p>
    <a>text</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a><img></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

So in this case, you can see that the structure of the two sections have nothing in common other than they contain links. I control the creation of the html around the containers, which have the class. The contents of those containers are completely dynamic, and in fact, the contents of the first could easily become the contents of the second, with the only thing remaining constant is the div and its code.

I suppose one approach would be to select all the links that fall below that class, and then add the class to those links as I add the click handler?

Comment: a sample piece of html code would better illustrate your problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can comma-separate several selectors:

```
$('.class1, .class2, .class3').each(function() { ... });
```

If `class1` is a container, you could of course access the `a` tag like so:

```
$('.class1 a, .class2 a, ...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$('.container1, .container2, .container3').find('a').on('click',function(){
   //link click handler
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all requirements, I would say it would be easier to select all A tags (or set a class on all A tags that is supposed to get the onlick and select by that) and then get the parent class in the click event with eg. .$(this).parent().attrib("class").

Give me som html and javascript, and I will give you a more visual example :)

Answer (score 0):

Without binding individual events or having the anchor know about its special parent, it might be tough to get the class you need.  You can use the event target to tell what was clicked, though:

```
$(".class1, .class2, .class3").click(function (e) {
   if (e.target.nodeName !== 'A') { return; }
   var cl = $(this).attr('class');
   //do whatever you want with $(e.target);
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/k2VuG/